# How to save calculated value from textbox in to the table

Tags: ms-access

How can i save a calculated value from textbox in to the table?
I tried to make my calculation as the default value, it's saving but if i change the input my calculation doesn't change. If i put it to into my Control Source i can't save it than.

Is it possible to save the calculation in to the table?

Kind Regards,
Lukso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most part, you need to use an event. The After Update event of a control is usually suitable. For example

```
 Form
 ---------------------------
 Amount : 10
 Tax    :  2
 Total  : 12  'Amount + Tax
```

With the above form, in the After Update event for Tax and for Amount, you could update the bound control Total to Amount + Tax.

```
Private Sub Amount_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Total = Me.Amount + Me.Tax
End Sub
```

As usual with calculations, you must ask yourself is it relevant to store this calculation or can it be obtained from a query?

Finally, with Access 2010 came [data macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973807.aspx) and [calculated columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff945943.aspx), which may also suit.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO` if you're making a new record 
or 
`UPDATE` if you're updating an existing one.

You might need a seperate unbound textbox that's hidden depending on what exactly you're doing.

This would update the field `fieldName` to the value of `fieldNameTextBox` where the record ID Autonumber field = the autonumber field on the form.

Insert Into has very similar syntax.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim RecordList As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set RecordList = db.OpenRecordset("qryClientSearch")
db.execute "UPDATE table1 SET table1.fieldName = """ & Me.fieldNameTextBox.Value & """ WHERE Table1.ID = " & Forms![FormName]![ID] & ""
```

Comment: If you run this is VBA on the form, you are likely to run into a problem with updating a record on both the form and through code. It is a common cause of several errors.

Comment: If you just did it onclick of a button control, add a requery, and have an unbound textbox as the control you're using (set equal to the value of a hidden bound control), would it still potentially update twice? All the data is going into the unbound control, so the form shouldn't update it, only the code.

Comment: There is a big difference between updating a control and updating a separate instance. If you add update buttons and so on, you are asking a lot from the user.

Comment: Doesn't this guy want to do more than just update the control though?

Comment: Updating a **bound** control will update the table / query just the same as typing into a bound control updates the table / query.

Comment: You're a wise man, I guess I was just over thinking his issue.