# Access, lookup for data in another table if matches update the current cell

Tags: sql, ms-access

I my access database i have two tables:

1. Master_Table
2. Material Return Data

In my material return data table , i need to update "complaint recived date" automatically based on the "complaint number"(both the column data is available in master table) & rest of the column data will entered manually.
To update "complaint recived date" automatically based on the "complaint number" , I have entered below sql query in the row source of the column , while running the query it is showing correct data but in the table it is not updating , kindly help me.

```
SELECT master_table.[Complaint Received On] FROM master_table WHERE (((master_table.[Complaint Number])=[Complaint_No]));
```

SQL query entered as row source:
[image: SQL query entered as row source]

Query result:
[image: Query window]
[image: Query result]

table image:
[image: Result not getting updated]

Comment: You have to use `UPDATE` query to update data to table. Raw source will show data, will not update.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate this date value into another table? Does a single complaint really have multiple received dates to choose from? If you have a combobox for selecting complaint, include its received date as another column then reference that combobox column to read its date.

Comment: An UPDATE query is not required. Can simply `Me.fieldname = Me.controlname`. The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into. However, really should not be duplicating data between tables. If you can calculate for saving, you can calculate when needed. Build query that joins tables to retrieve associated data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save calculated value from textbox in to the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253001/how-to-save-calculated-value-from-textbox-in-to-the-table)